# How to fast enumerate through an array of objects of type `NSClassFromString(className)`?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

```
Class class = NSClassFromString(className);
for (class *object in fetchedObjects) {

}
```

Hey guys! So I have the above code inside a method that accepts a class name and it doesn't work for some reason. It tells me `"Use of undeclared identifier 'object'` Anybody know what I can do to fix this? :\ It should be the same as saying:

```
for (NSObject *object in fetchedObjects) {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `id` instead of `NSObject`

```
Class class = NSClassFromString(className);
for (id object in fetchedObjects) {

}
```

Note that variables of type `id` aren't declared with an asterisk (`*`).

Comment: Hey nburk! So how do I create an object of type class? :O I kinda need it

Comment: that's a totally different question :D what kinds of objects are in the `fetchedObjects` array?

Comment: you can't particularly "create" objects to type `class`. however, you can retrieve the `class` of an _existing_ object by calling class `myClass =  [anObject class]`

Comment: Oh okay, that's a shame :( Thanks anyway!! I'll upvote your answer when the time's up :)

Comment: well, what's your plan? what do want to do with the objects in `fetchedObjects`?

Comment: I wanted to create a method that would accept a Class and an Array of objects! I know it doesn't sound very intuitive but I'm dealing with 5 different Arrays of different Types so I thought I'd save myself some typing :)